# how to resolve error with symfony ux component compiling

Tags: symfony

When i install UX Component like ux-chartjs per example i have this error when i compile with webpack encore ans component don't work :

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                                     15:01:04

error  in ./assets/controllers.json                                                                                                                                                                                                                        15:01:04

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@symfony/stimulus-bridge/dist/webpack/loader.js):
Error: The file "@symfony/ux-dropzone/package.json" could not be found. Try running "yarn install --force".
at createControllersModule (C:\laragon\www\DevQuizz\node_modules@symfony\stimulus-bridge\dist\webpack\loader.js:46:19)
at Object.loader (C:\laragon\www\DevQuizz\node_modules@symfony\stimulus-bridge\dist\webpack\loader.js:106:43)

Yarn install --force => not resolve problem

Comment: Looks like there is a backslash missing for some reason. `C:\laragon\www\DevQuizz\node_modules@symfony\stimulus-bridge\dist\webpack\loader.js:46:19` should most likely have a backslash between `node_modules` and `@symfony`

Comment: @TheDOK were you able to fix this issue? I have the same problem and can't manage to fix it.